# Why do you say j'ai mangé instead of j'ai manger?

Tags: grammaire

Why do you say j'ai mangé instead of j'ai manger?

Comment: Hi and welcome to French Language. Can you add some explanation of why you'd expect *j'ai manger*? And some background on your French level would be helpful. If you're just starting out it's a different kind of answer than if you're a French speaker wondering about why the language is like this.

Comment: You are most likely confused by past tense and using devoir. In French there are two verb to express *have*. One verb is *devoir* which means a requirement or must. Then you have *avoir* which is used as an auxiliary verb to compound verb tenses like the *passé composé*, it is also used as *have* to mean possesion (*I have a dog*)

Comment: j'ai manger doesn't exist. Very simple.

Answer (score 2):

I might not be an expert, but just thinking logically (and translating literally):
J'ai mangé. (I have eaten)
"Mangé" meaning "eaten". But when you say "J'ai manger" it would literally be translated as "I have eat", because "manger" is the infinitive.

Answer (score 2):

That's a very basic grammar concept. The past tense (passé composé) of a verb in -er is être or avoir + the past participle, -é.

- Je suis allé.
- J'ai mangé.
  Etc etc

Note the use of the accent on é. It's there for a reason, too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say "j'ai mange" mais "j'ai mangé". It is the past participle of "manger". J'ai manger* amounts to saying "I have do".

Answer (score 0):

Because the French language has **rules**!

"Mangé" = "eaten" (= past participle of "eat") in English. "J'ai" = "I have", as in either physical possession or "I have " in the past.

This implies that "J'ai mangé" = "I have eaten"!

The best way of seeing how wrong "J'ai manger" is to consider its best semi-literal translation which is "I must to eat".

"I must eat" = "Je dois manger" (which also means "I have to eat") so there is no translation of your phrase which makes sense in English!